# How to change the color code label on a graph in R using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm doing a case study, and I wanted to include some stuff made in R to practice my coding skills on that language.

According to my notes, I should be able to change the color code label with the `scale_colour_manual(name = "Region")` part, but on the graph it just don't make the change.

**Any ideas?**

[image]

Comment: Update: Sorry for not change the link description, here's the url for the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1ywA.png

Comment: Your graph is using `fill`, not `colour`, so you would need to use `scale_fill_manual`.

Answer (score 0):

In general, `ggplot` uses `colour` when referring to outlines, and `fill` when referring to the inside colour of a shape. In your example the colour of the plots is actually a `fill`. So you should be using

```
scale_fill_manual(name = "Region")
```

That should then do what you want it to.

Comment: It says that the function does not exist, I'm using ggplot2, but it worked using scale_fill_manual

Comment: You're right, that was a silly error from me! scale_fill_manual is what you want :)